# PHP - Rows are not in proper format after importing csv to mysql using LOAD INTO INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here. I would like to ask question regarding with my codes. So my code is working perfectly but then after importing csv to mysql programmatically using LOAD INTO INFILE. I didn't know why my output kept getting this kind of format. Please see my codes below thanks!

```
$testing = $conn->prepare("LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql/usagetable.csv'
            INTO TABLE trieinitialcountentry
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (Count_ID, InvItemLocID, OnHand, OnHandValue, StockCenter_ID)");
$testing->execute();
```

And also, some rows had been imported perfectly but some of them are not. Example of my output:

```
Count_ID InvItemLocID OnHand OnHandValue StockCenter_ID
737450   -2091889269  140.00  "2         788.80"
```

Comment: You should provide example of table structure and csv entries

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some of the values in the input CSV file are wrapped in quotes and you didn't pass this information to [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Try this query:

```
$query = <<<'END'
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql/usagetable.csv'
    INTO TABLE trieinitialcountentry
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (Count_ID, InvItemLocID, OnHand, OnHandValue, StockCenter_ID)
END;

$testing = $conn->prepare($query);
$testing->execute();
```

Note the added `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` clause.